# Не запускается проект в Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

После переустановки Android Studio стала недоступна кнопка "run" для старых проектов
Что делать?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста в вопросе, какие ошибки получаете. А то гадать долго можно.

Comment: @Xyz у вас не отрабатывает сборка gradle, и вам скорее всего надо бы обновить gradle

Answer (score 4):

Вообще есть 2 решения:

1. Проверь, подключен ли android-sdk к android-studio, если нет - то самое время его установить

   Попробуй подождать, если старый проект достаточно объемный, то Android Studio может просто долго грузится, такое случается
   Про добавление Android SDK в Android Studio можешь почитать [тут](http://www.fandroid.info/dobavlenie-paketov-android-sdk-manager)

Comment: SDK я скачал, когда создаю новый проэкт все работает, не запускаются только старые проэкты